# Erratum for Billingsley’s $\textit{Probability and Measure}$, Problem 32.13

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification

This is a **verification request for a counterexample** that I think I have found for Problem 32.13 on page 427 in Patrick Billingsley’s *Probability and Measure* textbook (third edition, but the problem appears unaltered in other editions, too).

---

The result to be proven in this problem is quoted (almost) verbatim:

> Suppose that $\mu$ is a Borel probability measure on $\mathbb R$, that $\nu$ is a $\sigma$-finite Borel measure on $\mathbb R$, and that $\nu\ll\mu$ (that is, $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$). Show that the Radon–Nikodym derivative $f$ satisfies $$\lim_{h\downarrow0}\frac{\nu(x-h,x+h]}{\mu(x-h,x+h]}=f(x)$$ on a set of $\mu$-measure $1$.

I can prove this result if $\nu$ is assumed to be finite (using an earlier result presented in Problem 31.22 on page 419; the key condition is the $\mu$-integrability of the Radon–Nikodym derivative), or even regular (that is, finite on compact sets—thanks to Dominique R.F. for pointing this out in a comment below). However, the assumption that $\nu$ is merely $\sigma$-finite (but potentially irregular) does not seem to be strong enough to ensure that the current result holds. I present a counterexample below, for which I welcome any feedback.

---

Let $p$ denote the point mass at the point $1/2$. This is a probability measure that assigns each Borel subset $A$ of the line a value $p(A)\in\{0,1\}$ according as $1/2\in A$ or $1/2\notin A$. Furthermore, let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure. Define, for each Borel set $A$, $$\mu(A)\equiv\frac{1}{2}\lambda(A\cap(0,1))+\frac{1}{2}p(A).$$ It is easy to check that $\mu$ is a probability measure on $\mathbb R$ and is supported on $(0,1)$. Furthermore, if $f:\mathbb R\to[0,\infty)$ is a real-valued, non-negative, Borel-measurable function, then it is not difficult to prove that $$\int f(t)\,\mathrm d\mu(t)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1f(t)\,\mathrm d t+\frac{1}{2}f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right),$$ where $\mathrm dt$ denotes simply integration with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

Now consider the following function on $\mathbb R$:
\begin{align*}
f(x)\equiv\begin{cases}\dfrac{1}{x-\dfrac{1}{2}}&\text{if $x>\dfrac{1}{2}$,}\\\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{2}-x}&\text{if $x<\dfrac{1}{2}$,}\\0&\text{if $x=\dfrac{1}{2}$.}\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Clearly, $f$ is real-valued, non-negative, and Borel-measurable.

Now define, for each Borel set $A$, $$\nu(A)\equiv\int_Af(t)\,\mathrm d\mu(t).$$ Then, $\nu$ is a measure and it is $\sigma$-finite, because letting $$A_n\equiv\{x\in\mathbb R\,|\,n-1\leq f(x)<n\}\quad\text{for each $n\in\mathbb N$},$$ it is easily seen that $$\mathbb R=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} A_n$$ (given that $f$ never assumes infinite or negative values) and that $$\nu(A_n)=\int_{A_n}f(t)\,\mathrm d\mu(t)\leq\int_{A_n}n\,\mathrm d\mu(t)=n\mu(A_n)\leq n<\infty$$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$. Furthermore, $\mu(A)=0$ implies that $\nu(A)=0$ for any Borel set $A$, and $f$ is the Radon–Nikodym derivative of $\nu$ with respect to $\mu$ (almost unique with respect to $\mu$).

Therefore, all the premises corresponding to Billingsley’s statement are satisfied. Letting $x=1/2$ and $h\in(0,1/2)$, one can see that $$\nu\left(\frac{1}{2}-h,\frac{1}{2}+h\right]=\int_{\left(\frac{1}{2}-h,\frac{1}{2}+h\right]}f(t)\,\mathrm d\mu(t)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\frac{1}{2}-h}^{\frac{1}{2}+h}f(t)\,\mathrm dt+\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}_{=0}=\infty,$$ given how $f$ has been defined. On the other hand, $\mu\left(\frac{1}{2}-h,\frac{1}{2}+h\right]=h+\frac{1}{2}>0,$ so that $$\lim_{h\downarrow0}\dfrac{\nu\left(\dfrac{1}{2}-h,\dfrac{1}{2}+h\right]}{\mu\left(\dfrac{1}{2}-h,\dfrac{1}{2}+h\right]}=\infty\neq0=f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right).$$ Hence, the conclusion does *not* hold at $x=1/2$, so it cannot hold almost everywhere with respect to $\mu$ given that $\mu(\{1/2\})=1/2>0$.

---

Clearly, $\nu$ in this counterexample is irregular; even though it is $\sigma$-finite, an infinite mass “accumulates” in arbitrarily small neighborhoods around the point $1/2$.

Comment: To corroborate your doubts, the corresponding theorem in Bogachev's Measure Theory (theorem 5.8.8) has the stronger hypothesis that $\nu$ is finite on all balls. This seems to be exactly what goes wrong in your example.

Comment: @DominiqueR.F. I see! So the key condition here seems to be _regularity_ as opposed to $\sigma$-finitude (of course, regularity is a stronger condition than $\sigma$-finitude and is weaker than finitude).